# Is there a playing node.js mp3 module that quickly loads and plays

Tags: node.js, audio

I want to play an mp3 sound in node.js and since I try modules but they take too much time to load and play the audio. I already try node-wav-player, audio-play, play-sound.
could someone tell me a quick module (serverside) like hower.js (clientside) to instantly play my mp3s? Thank you.

This code for audio-play:

```
const play = require('audio-play'); 
const load = require('audio-loader'); 
load('./sample.mp3').then(play);
```

but it takes too long time. I'm wondering if I can load audio since the beginning and play it after in the code when I need. I think it will take less time to play

Comment: Can you share what you've got already that's too slow?

Comment: These could be possible duplicate for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558763/playing-mp3-on-website-created-with-node-js

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619856/how-to-modify-a-mp3-metadata-and-save-by-node-js

Comment: this code for audio-play... @JoeyCiechanowicz                                            const play = require('audio-play');
const load = require('audio-loader');
 
load('./sample.mp3').then(play);

but it take too long time. I'm wondering if i can load audio since the beginning and play it after in the code when i need. Like that i think it will take less time to play

Comment: If you add that sample to your question to help others see what you've already tried